# Is it possible to enable a disabled breakpoint in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I wanted to know if it is possible to enable a disabled breakpoint programatically in Visual Studio. I am using Visual Studio 2008 but am interesting in know if this feature exists in other versions?

A little more info say i have two breakpoints in my code one at line 20 and one at line 30. The one in line 30 looks like this

```
if(someval==SomeRandomValue)
{
---->line 20 break point hit here
//I would like to enable the breakpoint at line 30 now as well (which was disabled)
}
```

Comment: Wait, are you creating a plugin for visual studio, or do you want to break in your code? Can you provide a bit more information?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, at least sort of. If you insert

```
Debugger.Break();
```

in your code, the debugger will break there if it is attached. It is explained at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> If no debugger is attached, users are asked if they want to attach a debugger. If yes, the debugger is started. If a debugger is attached, the debugger is signaled with a user breakpoint event, and the debugger suspends execution of the process just as if a debugger breakpoint had been hit.